# Laravel Query Builder - Use selected value in WHERE clause without repeating code

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to convert a RAW SQL query to Laravel Query builder, however I don't know how to use a derived value in the select statement in the WHERE clause. When doing this in RAW SQL I do this by nesting the select query.

Working RAW query

```
$query = DB::select("
        SELECT *
        FROM
          (SELECT DISTINCT a.postcode, b.id, b.name, d.product, e.distance product_distance,
                ROUND((SELECT 6371  * acos( cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( a.latitude ) )
                                                         * cos( radians( $lng ) - radians(a.longitude) )
                                                         + sin( radians( $lat ) ) * sin( radians( a.latitude ) ) ) ),0) AS point_distance
                FROM postcodes_geo AS a
                JOIN businesses As b
                    ON b.postcode = a.postcode
                JOIN business_services As c
                    ON b.id = c.business_id
                JOIN business_subscriptions As d
                    ON b.id = d.business_id
                JOIN ref_business_products AS e
                    ON d.product = e.product
                WHERE b.deleted_at IS NULL
                AND c.service = '$service'
                AND c.deleted_at IS NULL) t
                WHERE t.point_distance <= t.product_distance
          ORDER BY point_distance
          ");
```

[image: RAW SQL nested query]

Current query builder query

```
$query = DB::table('postcodes_geo')
            ->join('businesses', 'postcodes_geo.postcode', '=', 'businesses.postcode')
            ->join('business_services', 'businesses.id', '=', 'business_services.business_id')
            ->join('business_subscriptions', 'businesses.id', '=', 'business_subscriptions.business_id')
            ->join('ref_business_products', 'business_subscriptions.product', '=', 'ref_business_products.product')
            ->select(DB::raw("DISTINCT postcodes_geo.postcode, businesses.id, businesses.name, business_subscriptions.product, ref_business_products.distance,
                            ROUND((SELECT 6371  * acos( cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( postcodes_geo.latitude ) )
                                                         * cos( radians( $lng ) - radians(postcodes_geo.longitude) )
                                                         + sin( radians( $lat ) ) * sin( radians( postcodes_geo.latitude ) ) ) ),0) AS point_distance"))
            ->whereNull('businesses.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('business_services.deleted_at')
            ->when($services, function ($query, $services) {
                return $query->whereIn('business_services.service', explode(',', $services));
            })
            ->where(DB::raw("ROUND((SELECT 6371  * acos( cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( postcodes_geo.latitude ) )
                                                         * cos( radians( $lng ) - radians(postcodes_geo.longitude) )
                                                         + sin( radians( $lat ) ) * sin( radians( postcodes_geo.latitude ) ) ) ),0)"), "<=", 'ref_business_products.distance')
            ->get();
```

As you can see I don't want to repeat the same part of the query (it does work though).
[image: SQL query builder laravel]

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of MySQL's overloaded `HAVING` clause, which would allow you to refer to the `point_distance` alias defined in your select clause:

```
$query = DB::table('postcodes_geo')
    ...
    ->having(DB::raw('point_distance <= ref_business_products.distance'))
    ->get();
```

Note: If you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 5.7.5, then you would need to turn off `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode to use the overloaded `HAVING` as is being done in my answer.

Comment: I get an exception:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'distance' is used in HAVING clause.

I changed 'strict' => true, to false but then it returns no results

Comment: The alias in the code you actually posted is called `point_distance`, not `distance`.  Are you sure you are using my exact answer?

Comment: Exactly the same.

->having(DB::raw('point_distance <= ref_business_products.distance'))

Comment: @DLO I can only speculate that maybe you are using an older version of MySQL, earlier than 5.7.5, see my updated answer.  You may have to change your server mode.